# How reply a message useing office365 with php

Tags: php, ms-office, outlook-restapi

I am using office365 app and referenced from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations#Createandsendmessages and https://dev.outlook.com/RestGettingStarted/Tutorial/php create a function:

```
function reply_to(){
    $comment =array("Comment"=> $_POST['comment']);

    $url="https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/messages/'".$_POST['messeg_id']."'/reply";

    $data=OutlookService::makeApiCall($_SESSION['access_token'],'POST',$url,$comment);
    print_r($data);     
}
```

and always getting the same error

> Array ( [errorNumber] => 400 [error] => Request returned HTTP error 400 ).

I don't know what I am doing wrong I have checked multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of problems:

1. Remove the single-quotes `'` around your message ID in the URL.
2. JSON encode the `$comment` array before passing it to `makeApiCall` like so: `$comment = json_encode(array("Comment"=> $_POST['comment']));`

If you don't JSON encode, then cURL sends the data a form-encoded, rather than as a JSON entity in the body. The server rejects it with a 400 because it's invalid JSON.

Comment: Thanks for reply, Now i am removed single quotes from URL but again the same error occurred.                                                                                                                     function reply_to(){
  $comment =array("Comment"=> $_POST['comment']);  $url="https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/messages/".$_POST['messeg_id']."/reply";
  print_r($url);
  $data=OutlookService::makeApiCall($_SESSION['access_token'],'POST',$url,$comment);
  print_r($data);
  
  }

Comment: Ok. I updated my answer after trying it here. cURL doesn't send the array as JSON by default.

Comment: ok, but if i am sending the normal php array like array("Comment"=> $_POST['comment']) this shows the same error

Comment: Right. That's the problem. A non-encoded PHP array gets transmitted as form-encoded data, which is not what the mail API expects. It has to be JSON-encoded.

Comment: i do this but it also not working. Giving same error. i.e. Array ( [errorNumber] => 400 [error] => Request returned HTTP error 400 ).